# Storyboard UITableViewCell autolayout with 2 multiline UILabels inside

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, autolayout

I have two labels inside a cell and I want them to dynamically adjust height (number of lines is set to 0).

Constraints are very basic and easy to reproduce in fresh Master-Detail project. Top Label has Leading, Top, Trailing and the bottom Label has Leading, Bottom, Trailing. It is fine until I add Vertical Spacing between both labels. At this point Autolayout gets conflicts that I cannot resolve. Please se attached image.

What is interesting is that I have similar layout in another cell and works perfectly without any Autolayout conflicts. I'm scratching my head bald with this one.

[image: Autlayout confilcts]

Comment: You need to set height of the label. if it is multiline labels then you can set height >= 20 or the value you want to set

Comment: Very interesting. It is sufficient to set height >= constraint on one label only. It doesn't matter which. But the value has to be 22 or more, otherwise I see red lines again.